# What model is this old child’s bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, children

I found this in my grandfathers garage. He said it was in the garbage like 15 years ago. I don’t know but hope it’s something cool and antique. I am crossing my fingers.

[image: full view]

[image: serial number]

[image: saddle close-up]

[image: cranks]

[image: handlebars]

Comment: There's something on the head tube, can you post a picture of that ?

Comment: These were mass produced in the 70s before BMX was invented https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheelie_bike

Comment: Observation: this bike has two brakes, and a separate third white wire down on the "top" tube.   That could be a gear shifter for an internal-gear hub.   Looks like a loverly cleanup project, with only one or two parts missing.  Do search the garage for the seat support bar.

Answer (score 6):

That’s a Rollfast Skoot, probably late 60s or early 70s.

If you were hoping it’s valuable, in its current condition it’s probably not worth very much. There’s a nearly identical but fully restored one on eBay right now. Keep an eye on that and see if it sells for asking price or not. Then you can decide if you want to put the time and money into restoring it.

[image: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-1970s-Rollfast-SKOOT-Muscle-BICYCLE-Banana-Seat-COOL-/392271600909 from https://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-1970s-Rollfast-SKOOT-Muscle-BICYCLE-Banana-Seat-COOL-/392271600909]

Comment: I'd also point out to OP that the rear support stay for the saddle is missing, so as pictured its not safe to ride.  The saddle may flop down dumping the rider onto the back wheel.